# Failed to connect to development server using "adb reverse": spawnSync adb ENOENT

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, adb, enoent

My ReactNative application is running fine on Iphone simulator but when I tried to run it on my android mobile device via USB,it's throwing me this error.

```
        > Task :app:installDebug
    Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'SM-N770F - 10' for app:debug
    Installed on 1 device.
    
    Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
    Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
    See https://docs.gradle.org/6.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
    
    BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2m 17s
    227 actionable tasks: 227 executed
    info Connecting to the development server...
    warn Failed to connect to development server using "adb reverse": spawnSync adb ENOENT
    info Starting the app...
    error Failed to start the app. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

I have the environment variable setup and its working fine. In terminal, my adb devices are being listed successfully. Thanks in advance.
Edit: The application is installed in the device but it doesnt open upon installation plus its not reflecting the changes that I am doing. I can see the changes on emulator though

Comment: Its the node metro bundler. Doesnt have any issue normally on other systems, the debug apk is running fine.

Answer (score 0):

So when I tried to create an apk and test the application, it showed me multiple errors after the apk build was successful. In my case it were these :
[“Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51341627/android-gives-error-cannot-fit-requested-classes-in-a-single-dex-file)
[AsyncStorage is null iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63493043/error-reactnative-asyncstorage-is-null-ios)

So after applying the solution, the apk was generated successfully and when I tried to run application via USB,it worked fine.